# NSOperation to all run consequently

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, nsoperation

I have program that is crashing somewhere not really visible to programmer. It may have something to do with memory management but it definitively has something to do with multiple threads and more than 200 notification observers...

I would like to know if that kind of starting derived NSOperation object would ensure that all operations are being executed consequently as normal execution on one thread?

```
[operation start];
[operation waitUntilFinished];
```

Comment: I would ask my esteemed colleagues to look at http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down before voting down again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it starts the operation and then blocks the calling thread until it is done.

Comment: So, basically, if all Operations are started from the main thread in this way, this will practically ensure consequent execution. Would zoo agree with that?

Comment: Technically, yes. But you will be blocking the main thread, which is very bad! You'll want to create a `NSOperationQueue`, set the `operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1` and then add the operations to the queue. Also, if you are developing for iOS4+, look into Grand Central Dispatch, which makes life a lot easier in a lot of cases.

Comment: @hypercrypt More accurately, it will block the thread you call it from. If you use this construct from the main thread, then you're quite right, that it's bad practice. But it's not entirely unusual to submit an operation from a background queue to another queue (e.g. to another, serial queue which is synchronizing access to some shared resource), in which case, this construct is fine.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're looking for is `operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1` and then add all your operations to the `NSOperationQueue`. They will be executed serially, one after another.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, NSOperationQueue will ensure that only one additional thread for all operations is created and that they are ran one after another. Any idea what happens if op fails or hangs with uncaught exception or becomes uncontrollable in any way? Will Execution of whole queue stop or will queue just start next operation?

Comment: @nmpro: Yes, it will create only one additional thread. I'm not sure what happens if an exception is thrown; the queue may eat the exception and continue or it might crap out. It would be easy to test it to find out. If an operation hangs, the queue will hang.